# Delete folders in DB

Tags: php, sql, algorithm

i have gallery in site, i need delete all folders

my scructure DB: (g_folder)

```
id id_parent
1    0
2    0
3    2
4    2
5    3
```

for example

so, have i can delete folder AND delete all parent folder?

recursion?

```
function delete(folder)
{
  count = select id from g_folder where id_parent = folder
  if(count == 0)
    deleteFolderById(folder)

  while(count != 0)
  {
     array = select id from g_folder where id_parent = folder
     for i in range(count)
     {
       deleteFolderById(array[i])
     }
     count = select id from g_folder where id_parent = folder
     delete(array[0])          
  } 

}
```

my algorithm it`s wrong, please help! thanks all!

Comment: What database engine is this? You should probably implement this using foreign keys with `ON DELETE CASCADE` in the database itself and avoid the application-side logic altogether.

Comment: Delete all parents recursively? Are you sure? That may just flush your whole table.

Comment: why cant u delete directly with delete from g_folder where parent_id=$parent

Comment: If an item has an id = 1 and a parent id = 0, then both the child and the parent are in the same folder. So why don't delete the holde folder once?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
function deletefolder($parentid)
{
    $query="select * from g_folder where parentid=".$parentid;
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            deletefolder($row['id']);
        }
        $fdquery="delete from g_folder where parentid=".$parentid;
        $fdresult=mysql_query($fdquery);
    }

    $sdquery="delete from g_folder where id=".$parentid;
    $sdresult=mysql_query($sdquery);
}

deletefolder(2);
```